# what should CPU normally be on a xp spc3

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I really dont know much about this but i am wondering what the CPU should normally be ,i can be playing a game atta site and all of a sudden it just stops and i can look down on my task bar and see 00 on the name of place im playing.My CPU fluctuates from 0to bout 50 mostly thats what it is doing now my PFU is just sitting on 473MB doest move on the Commit Charge it has 473M/1799 and there will be  lil green looks like monitor with the green goimg up n down like its not full or something ,,just trying to figure this stuff out,i constantly hear a fan running to

Comment: What is your question?  This doesn't make much sense as written and will probably be closed...it's too incoherent.  Can you please clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Agreed, I couldn't really make sense of this.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are asking about how busy your CPU should be when you are doing normal activity on your computer.  It also appears you don't have a lot of experience speaking this lingo :-).

Anyway, This is extremely subjective question.  In general terms, your PC will respond ok to you so long as it is not pegged to 100% CPU continuously.  If it is in the 0-50 range you mention, it will be fine - from a CPU perspective.

You could also be memory starved.  You've given us the Page FIle size, but we need to know how much physical memory is in the PC.  You should see that on the same screen as PFU.  My best guess (and it is a guess) is your PC is swapping because it is low on memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "normal performance".  There's a technique called establishing a baseline.  A baseline is where you measure performance data over time on a particular computer.  The data is used as a baseline to compare against future changes in performance.  This way you can tell where performance is degrading when an issue comes up.

Now, if you are sitting at 100% CPU for long periods of time or using all your memory then these are bad things.  But, that's not what you have explained the issue to be.

Finally, typically a problem is only noticed when a bottleneck occurs.  In other words, if you are playing a game and everything is choppy.  Something is wrong, but at this point you don't know if its memory, CPU, video card or whatever.  Having an established baseline will make it easier to see where a major change has occurred so you can figure out what hardware is in need of an upgrade (similar techniques exist in software too).

See [benchmarking.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmarking)